# What is the default number of centroid, when we are using kknn in R?

Tags: r, classification

When I was learning kknn in R, I came across the IRIS data example, I found kknn does not take any argument of centroid numbers.

```
require(kknn)
data(iris)
m <- dim(iris)[1]
val <- sample(1:m, size = round(m/3), replace = FALSE, prob = rep(1/m, m)) 
iris.learn <- iris[-val,]   # train
iris.valid <- iris[val,]    # test
iris.kknn <- kknn(Species~., iris.learn, iris.valid, distance = 1, kernel ="triangular")
```

How does it optimize the number of centroid?

I remember `knn` takes argument of centroid number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of `kknn` package there is an argument to determine the number of centroids and that is argument `k`.

From [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kknn/kknn.pdf):

> k: Number of neighbors considered.

The default value is 7 centroids. Your can be written as:

```
require(kknn)
data(iris)
m <- dim(iris)[1]
val <- sample(1:m, size = round(m/3), replace = FALSE, prob = rep(1/m, m)) 
iris.learn <- iris[-val,]   # train
iris.valid <- iris[val,]    # test
iris.kknn <- kknn(Species~., iris.learn, iris.valid, 
                  distance = 1, kernel ="triangular", k=7)
#you can add whichever number you want above
```